# How to add a caption to an image attachment in a file list?

Tags: attachments, captions

I've tried various things and can't get the captions to show up in my gallery. I'm using CMB2's file list to output image attachments. I hope this question is pertinent enough to this forum as I think I'm just missing some simple php or wordpress function. Currently, it does output the image and the empty p tags. Thanks for any help!

In the past I've used `echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;` in the post template.

```
function soth_output_gallery_file_list( $file_list_meta_key, $img_size ) {

// Get the list of files
$files = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $file_list_meta_key, 1 );

echo '<div class="entry-content row">';

  foreach ( (array) $files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url ) {
    echo '<div class="small-6 medium-4 column text-center">';
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $img_size );
    echo '<p class="wp-caption-text">';
//what am I missing?
    echo $missingSomething->post_excerpt;
    echo '</p></div>';
  }

echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Why not using the same line again `echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;` ?

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't get that to work. I've also tried `get_post_meta(get_the_ID())->post_excerpt;`... That's what makes me think I'm writing it with the wrong WP function or php syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to pass `$attachment_id` instead of `get_post_thumbnail_id()` in `echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;` with [`wptexturize`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) to prevent your markup from breaking other things.

**Update**: As @birgire suggested I think it is better to use [`get_post_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field) instead of directly accessing post property.

Updated code:-

```
function soth_output_gallery_file_list( $file_list_meta_key, $img_size ) {

    // Get the list of files
    $files = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $file_list_meta_key, 1 );

    echo '<div class="entry-content row">';

        foreach ( (array) $files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url ) {
            echo '<div class="small-6 medium-4 column text-center">';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $img_size );
            echo '<p class="wp-caption-text">';

            //Get post excerpt by attachment ID
            echo wptexturize( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id ) );
            echo '</p></div>';
        }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Yes! That works. Thanks very much. That's what I was missing, I didn't know how to get that object and that I needed to use it as a variable. I've got a lot to learn still and appreciate your help.

Comment: Another option could be through  [get_post_field()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field) and note that `wptexturize()` will not escape possible HTML code in the excerpt or fix problematic HTML code. What about `esc_html()` ? @BradH Please accept the answer if it solved the problem, to close the question, thanks.

Comment: @birgire Thanks! I think it is better to use `get_post_field` to allow filters and saving few lines (`isset()` etc). But I am not sure about `esc_html()` here. I used `wptexturize()` because default gallery shortcode uses it. For me I never put HTML in excerpt :D

Comment: Another question if I may (or do I need to ask a new one??)... In order to get an image to open in my lightbox, I need it to link to the attachment. I've added the variable `$link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_obj ); ` and  `echo '<a href="'. $link .'">';` and it just goes to the post page that the gallery is on. But that's the only think remotely close to working I've tried...

Comment: @BradH That should be an another question :) but you can try `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` instead of `wp_get_attachment_url()` if it works. And do not forgot to check [codex examples](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback, Sumit. I did get it to work with `echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'full' );`. Trying to echo it as a variable doesn't work I guess.